# How do I allow users to write python code that runs with using code on the backend?

Tags: python, django

So I have a Django Application that uses a "framework" we have created that includes methods and classes that are known to the user. I want to implement a feature such that the user can write code on the website's provided editor, which would then include this framework library and display the code written.

I am using Django and I am not sure how would I be able to execute the code and display the returning values from the code written by the user.

Comment: You are opening yourself up to a huge can of worms here; letting users run arbitrary Python code has huge security implications. The general answer is: Don't do it, use a domain-specific language instead. The next best option: run the Python code in a virtual machine that you shut down after a short timeout, and which you give no network capacity whatsoever.

Comment: Is there a way to do this? Could you guide me to resources?